# What is a good language to work with arbitrary length integers?

Tags: programming-languages, factorization

I want to factorise integers, for example

> 41748850938502584251

I want to factorise this using brute-force. Given the short length of this number this should be possible.

What's a suitable programming language which supports an integer data type that has arbitrary length?

Comment: Most languages will do this for you.  This isn't sufficient reason to pick one over the other. Just pick one.

Comment: C and C++ can use the GMP arbitrary precision library, which is very good. Java has built-in arbitrary-precision integers. JavaScript does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scheme has a featureful [numeric tower](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-6.html#node_sec_3.1) that provides, among other things, arbitrary precision integers (see [sec. 3.4](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-2.html#node_toc_node_sec_3.4) of R6RS which requires this of conforming implementations).

Comment: I have a small library of functions in Scheme that provides (prime n) to make a list of primes not exceeding n using the sieve of Eratosthenes, (prime? n) to determine if n is prime by the Miller/Rabin test, and (factors n) to find the factors of n using Pollard's rho algorithm. You can see it handle your factorization problem at [http://ideone.com/x4tzl](http://ideone.com/x4tzl).

Answer (score 0):

Java's BigInteger class handles very large numbers: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use Perl.  Put

```
use bigint;
```

at the beginning of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Haskell has the Integer data type for unlimited integers.
Likewise Frege (it uses Javas big integers).